# Symfony DomCrawler Equivalent in Python

Tags: php, python, symfony, domcrawler

Are there any python libraries out there that work like [Symfony's `DomCrawler`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dom_crawler.html)?  I would like to use CSS selectors in order to extract data from some HTML.

The functionality I'm most interested in would be something similar to this snippet of PHP:

```
$crawler = new Crawler($html);
$crawler = $crawler->filter('body > p');
```

If there is any default functionality in python that allows this to be accomplished easily, that would work as well.

Comment: Have you looked at scrapy? http://scrapy.org/

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, I forgot about scrapy, but it looks like it does use CSS selectors or XPath expressions, so this will work perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, I have used it myself and I would highly recommend it.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, Do you happen to know if it breaks with malformed HTML, or does it do pretty well at recovering?

Comment: It uses lxml to build the Selectors, lxml handles broken html,  to how bad I don't really know. All I can say is I never had issues. http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html

Comment: @PadraicCunningham, ok cool.  thanks for the additional info Padraic.